# Rails Autosave form with jquery

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, jquery

I am working on application where a a user can create a blog post and the blog post periodically updates every so often. I found a [jQuery autosave plugin](https://github.com/nervetattoo/jquery-autosave) for handling the autosave but I am still running into problems.

1. When I debug using firebug I only see the GET request so therefore the page does not get updated and I am not sure how to call POST after the GET request.
2. It does not update as I type or every 3 seconds but it updates when I click outside of a form field. Anyway to have it so it updates every 3 seconds or so?

My code is listed below

**application.js**

```
    jQuery(function($) {
      $("#main-form").autosave({
        callbacks: {
          trigger: ["change", function() {
            var self = this;

            $("[name=save]").click(function() {
              self.save();
            });
          }],
          save: {
            method: "ajax",
            options: {
              success: function() {
                alert("saved!");
              }
            }
          }
        }
      });
    });
```

**post_controller.rb**

```
def update
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])

  respond_to do |format|
    if @post.update_attributes(params[:post])
      format.html { redirect_to semester_post_path, notice: 'post was successfully updated.' }
      format.json { head :ok }
    else
      format.html { render action: "edit" }
      format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sure you've moved on, but just to close the gap on this post. OnChange takes place when a field loses focus, so what you're seeing seems to be functioning as designed and normal for that design.

Here's a link to question/answer using [timeouts to autosave via AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14991046/autosaving-a-form-in-rails-with-ajax).

**Autosave Opinion:**

I'm not sure you *really* want envoke autosave until the document has been formally submitted for several reasons but I'll post my favorite 2.

1. Some forms tend to have a lot of moving parts for the back end storage and that first commit should be intentional before stuffing a bunch of data into tables. (IMHO)
2. another rationale behind leaving them alone (not auto-saving) before the first "real" submit is because until they hit submit they might not really want you to have that information in your system.

How often have you started a form on the web and then decided you didn't want to fill out that information after all? ... it would frustrate me to get a flyer or email or call from a site I actually decided to bail out of registration for!